# Creating a multi-column view on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I just got a design handed to me for implementation. At the moment this view should list elements vertically in two columns (I imagine that this would translate to more columns on the upcoming design for iPad), all of which with a maximum width equal to that of the column width but different heights (determined by the ratio of the image). As the user scrolls down more items should be added to the flow, most probably to alternating columns. I.e. I need to determine the height of the object/cell and then determine which column to add this to. Also the items should be able to handle clicks.

[image: Flow of application]

My first thought was UITableView, then UIScrollView and lastly UICollectionView (I haven't worked with UICollectionView before).

How would you go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is the way to go, for sure.

Take a look at [this layout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout).

Comment: Of course, Waterfall is this kind of behaviour called! Will look into this!

Answer (score 1):

Your last choice is the best -> UICollectionView.
You can define a custom layout.

Take a look on this: https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout